# NOT rendering searched items in Search box used thinking-sphinx Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, thinking-sphinx

as i am a beginner to rails...
i have installed gem 'thinking-sphinx' (3.1.3, 2.0.10) in my file using rails4
and rvm 2.0.0
i wrote this action in my controller[image: patients.rb]

and inside index page added form_tag [image: patients/index.html.erb]

in the same file added this script[image: patients/index.html.erb]

in search box its not showing searched results[image]
but in terminal it is showing as[image: terminal view]

routes.rb

```
resources :patients do member do 
  put :update_status 
end 
collection do 
  get :search get :search_sphinx 
end
```

Comment: What code are you using to parse the JSON that you're getting back from the search_sphinx action. Also, can you show us your route?

Comment: You're not actually using Sphinx anywhere in the code you've shared - instead of calling `Patient.where`, you should be using `Patient.search :first_name => params[:q], :star => true`. Of course, you'll need an index defined for your Patient model that has a first_name field included for this to work.

Comment: Also, I would recommend using `render :json => [...]` instead of `render :text => ...`, because that'll ensure the content-type in your responses is sent appropriately.

Comment: thanks for ur replys but i didnt get the expected output by ur suggestions please answer me  @pat........ after updating render :json => [...] and Patient.search :first_name => params[:q], :star => true...........................................i am getting error: NameError (undefined local variable or method `patients' for #<PatientsController:0x9e08680>):
  app/controllers/patients_controller.rb:63:in `search_sphinx' @pat

Comment: resources :patients do member do put :update_status end collection do get :search get :search_sphinx end end these are my routes in routes.rb inside config @NickM

Comment: As Pat said (you should trust him, he is the lead contributor to the thinking-sphinx gem), you're not actually using Sphinx anywhere. You should check out the docs here http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/

Comment: ya i trusted him but in rails3 the code which i have shown in my question is working but in rails4 that code is not working to display the searched results in search box.........but in terminal i can see the searched results @NickM

Comment: while typing related names i wants to get the search related names in the search box that's my requirement.... i hope u got my point now....@NickM and @pat